# How to conditionally shift cells upward

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel VBA macro to process a range of cells and shift non-zero cells upward while preserving empty rows that contain only 0 values.

[image: This is the data]

I get an object required error and the debugger points to the while loop.

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Dim firstColumn As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
    Set currentCell = ws.Range("A2")
    Set lastCell = ws.Range("KL3602")
    firstColumn = currentCell.Column

    While currentCell.Row <= lastCell.Row
        If currentCell.Value = 0 Then
            ' Delete the current cell and shift cells up
            currentCell.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            
            ' Set the nextCell after deletion
            Set nextCell = currentCell
        Else
            ' Move to the next cell
            Set nextCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
        ' Move to the next cell
        Set currentCell = nextCell
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Every time you use `Delete` method, the reference of the `currentCell` varable is lost. So the variable points to no object. This is why this error is raised.

Comment: So if i try to store it in another varable and then reasign it, that should fix it ?

Comment: No I thing this will end up with the same problem. I would try storing the address of the currentCell before deleting it. Or maybe the row and column if it is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problem identified by @mits then don't store the Range at all ... start from the last row and work upwards eg

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
    For i = 3602 To 2 Step -1
        With ws.Range("A" & i)
            If .Value = 0 Then
                .Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

... this deletes the '0' cells in column A (I believe that is what you wanted to do ... not delete the entire row?)

**EDIT FOR UPDATE FROM OP**

You could try this, which will delete all cells with a '0' value anywhere in Sheet4 cells A2 to KL3602 which seems to be the cells referred to in your questions

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range, allCells As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
    For Each cel In ws.Range("A2:KL3602")
        If cel.Value = 0 Then
            If allCells Is Nothing Then
                Set allCells = cel
            Else
                Set allCells = Union(allCells, cel)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel
    allCells.Delete XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp
End Sub
```

This will take a few seconds to run. If you want to change it to work on a different range then just change range of cells in the `For Each cel In ws.Range("A2:KL3602")` line to meet your needs.

Comment: What i want to do is delete the 0 cells from all the table range and shift the cells with data to the top

Comment: Like if i have a name on the other 3 rows a 0 then another name i want to delete the cells with 0 in them and move the names next to each other

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean (you might want to add an image of your data to the question) ... do you mean you want to delete the whole row when column A (or some other column) has a cell with a '0' value or do you mean that you want to independently delete all '0' cells from multiple columns (if so, which columns)?

Comment: I've added a picture in the post, hope it makes sens.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentCell As Range
    Dim lastCell As Range
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Dim firstColumn As Long
'add this variable
Dim currRow as Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")
    Set currentCell = ws.Range("A2")
    Set lastCell = ws.Range("KL3602")
    firstColumn = currentCell.Column

    While currentCell.Row <= lastCell.Row
        If currentCell.Value = 0 Then
'add this line
            currRow = currentCell.Row
            ' Delete the current cell and shift cells up
            currentCell.Delete Shift:=xlUp
'change this line
            ' Set the nextCell after deletion
            Set nextCell = ws.Range("A" & currRow)
        Else
            ' Move to the next cell
            Set nextCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        
        
        ' Move to the next cell
        Set currentCell = nextCell
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: THX for the suggestion, i'll try run it and see what it gets me